# UnsatisfiedLinkError running voldemort with Maxine

Tags: java, jna, voldemort

I was trying to use maxine to run a single node cluster on Voldemort and ran into this problem. It seems to be related to JNA? Could you please help me?

Here is the command that I used:

```
  ./maxine/com.oracle.max.vm.native/generated/linux/maxvm -cp .voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/dist/voldemort-1.9.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/dist/voldemort-1.9.0-src.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/dist/voldemort-contrib-1.9.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/dist/voldemort-test-1.9.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/avro-1.4.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/azkaban-common-0.05.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/catalina-ant.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/colt-1.2.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/commons-pool-1.5.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/compress-lzf-0.9.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/data-1.15.18.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/hadoop-auth-2.0.5-alpha.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/httpcore-4.1.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jdom-1.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/je-5.0.88.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jetty-6.1.18.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jetty-util-6.1.18.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jna.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/joda-time-1.6.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/jopt-simple-4.6.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/junit-4.6.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/krati-0.3.6.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/libthrift-0.5.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/netty-3.5.8.Final.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/paranamer-2.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/pegasus-common-1.15.18.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/protobuf-java-2.3.0.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/r2-1.15.18.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/scala-compiler-2.10.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/scala-library-2.10.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/scala-reflect-2.10.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/snappy-0.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/tehuti-0.5.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/tusk-0.0.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/typica-1.7.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/velocity-1.6.2.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/contrib/*/lib/*.jar:.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/dist/resources -Dlog4j.configuration=file://.voldemort/voldemort-release-1.9.0-cutoff/src/java/log4j.properties -Xmx2G -server -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote voldemort.server.VoldemortServer config/single_node_cluster/
```

The error output that i obtained:

> [14:38:18,735 voldemort.store.metadata.MetadataStore] INFO metadata
>   init(). [main] [14:38:18,999 voldemort.cluster.Node] WARN admin-port
>   not defined for node:0 using default value(socket_port + 1):6667
>   [main] [14:38:19,086 voldemort.store.metadata.MetadataStore] INFO
>   Updating routing strategy for all stores [main] [14:38:20,163
>   voldemort.server.VoldemortServer] INFO Using NIO Connector. [main]
>   [14:38:20,304 voldemort.server.VoldemortServer] INFO Using NIO
>   Connector for Admin Service. [main] [14:38:20,306
>   voldemort.common.service.VoldemortService] INFO Starting
>   voldemort-server [main] [14:38:20,425 voldemort.utils.JNAUtils] INFO
>   Failed to link to native library [main] Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Java_voldemort_utils_JNAUtils_mlockall
>   __I   at com.sun.max.vm.jni.DynamicLinker.lookup(DynamicLinker.java:271)  at
>   com.sun.max.vm.actor.member.NativeFunction.link0(NativeFunction.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.max.vm.actor.member.NativeFunction.link(NativeFunction.java:110)
>     at voldemort.utils.JNAUtils.mlockall(Native Method)     at
>   voldemort.utils.JNAUtils.tryMlockall(JNAUtils.java:51)    at
>   voldemort.server.VoldemortServer.startInner(VoldemortServer.java:328)
>     at
>   voldemort.common.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:62)
>     at voldemort.server.VoldemortServer.main(VoldemortServer.java:384)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.max.vm.run.java.JavaRunScheme.lookupAndInvokeMain(JavaRunScheme.java:376)
>     at com.sun.max.vm.run.java.JavaRunScheme.run(JavaRunScheme.java:333)
>     at com.sun.max.vm.thread.VmThread.executeRunnable(VmThread.java:511)
>     at com.sun.max.vm.thread.VmThread.run(VmThread.java:682)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to edit it such that the command is more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the missing implementation of the `sun.misc.Unsafe.getLoadAverage` method in Maxine VM.

Commit https://github.com/beehive-lab/Maxine-VM/commit/9f36e8a1d9fa54d74b8bfa3f632814a7be9e2ae2 works around this issue till an actual implementation is provided.